# json_object_object_add, segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linux, libjson

I am using `libjosn-c` as below and encounter a Segmentation fault error.

If I remove the line `json_object_object_add(root, "Child", value);`, no error occurs.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    json_object *root = NULL, *value = NULL;

    root = json_object_new_string("My Object");
    value = json_object_new_string("My Child Object");
    json_object_object_add(root, "Child", value);
    printf("to string =%s\n", json_object_to_json_string(root));

    json_object_put(value);
    json_object_put(root);

    return 0;
}
```

I am not experienced in `libjson-c`.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd read the [documentation](http://json-c.github.io/json-c/json-c-0.12/doc/html/files.html) of a library before starting to use it.

As described [here](http://json-c.github.io/json-c/json-c-0.12/doc/html/json__object_8h.html#a04448b1c63173e1bfe49965835732075) `json_object_object_add(root, "Child", value)` transfers the ownership of `value` to `root`. It means you are no longer responsible for `json_object_put`ing it. When you `json_object_put` the `root` it `json_object_put`s the `value` for you.

When you `json_object_put` the `value`, it's reference counter drops to 0 and it's memory gets freed. When you `json_object_put` the `root`, it attempts to `json_object_put` the `value` and fails because the `value` no longer exists.

If you don't want the `value` to outlive the `root`, just remove the `json_object_put(value)` line.

If you want to use `value` after `root` gets freed, use:

`json_object_object_add(root, "Child", json_object_get(value))`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply!

As I understand your explanation, just remove the line `json_object_put(value);`

However, I don't understand why the line `json_object_object_add(root, "Child", value);` causes error.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you please [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) then?

Answer (score 0):

Because json_object_put(root) frees all the objects it owns too. Since you added "value" to "root" when you did the put(root) it also did the put(value). By having your json_object_put(value), you freed the memory for value, and when you did the json_object_put(root) it also tried to free the memory for value, and since it was already freed, you caused a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `json_type` of `root`.  Your program creates two instances of `json_type_string`, to which you attempt to add a key/value pair to the one called `root`.  The json-c library should have probably detected the incorrect `json_type` of `root` and ignored the add request or something, but instead crashes on the call to `json_object_object_add(root, "Child", value);` (the crash can be replicated at least in v0.11 of json-c).

If instead, you wrote the program like:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  json_object *root = NULL, *value = NULL;

  root = json_object_new_object();                    /* json_type_object */
  value = json_object_new_string("My Child Object");  /* json_type_string */
  json_object_object_add(root, "Child", value);
  printf("to string =%s\n", json_object_to_json_string(root));

  json_object_put(root);

  return 0;
}
```

it works and returns the output

```
to string ={ "Child": "My Child Object" }
```

You can use functions like `json_object_get_type()` to determine the `json_type` of a `json_object`if you write a function which takes one as a parameter.